# Android reads empty file, ADB shows that file is not empty

Tags: java, android, file

I try to read a log file of another application on Android.

To read the file, I use the following code:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return text.toString();
```

And I have a loop which reads the file every second:

```
while(true) {
    Log.i("FileCheckTask", "Log file size: " + mLogFile.length());
    SleepSeconds(1);
}
```

And this loop always writes `Log file size: 0` for the first ~10 iterations, although in the Android Studio Device File Explorer I can see that the file has 34,4 KB. Also the functions above returns an empty string.

After the 10 iterations, the file size is reported correctly and the above function reads the correct content.

Why does this happen and how can I read the file faster, without waiting for ~10 seconds?

Comment: Do you know about file permissions in linux? have you checked, that your application is allowed to read the others apps logs? just because adb can doesn't mean another app should be allowed to (if not explicitly granted by the other app)

Comment: Yes, I'm able to read this file. After the 10 seconds, the method returns the complete content of the file.

Comment: Is it possible that the file is locked?